# How can I use a data validation dropdown that allows users to add new numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I want to place a dropdown in a cell in Google Sheets that contains a list of words for users to choose from.

I also want users to be able to ignore the words in the list and instead enter any number.

Currently, when a user inputs a value that is not in the list it displays an error message.

How can I allow users to select from the dropdown or enter a number without triggering an error?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 9 times.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using dropdown that uses a range to populate its list.

Any user-entered numbers will be added to the dropdown for future users

### Instructions

Assumes your dropdowns are in `Sheet1!D2:D`. Adjust as necessary.

1. Place your list of items you'd like in your dropdown somewhere in your spreadsheet. For example, in `Sheet2!A:A`
2. In `Sheet2!B1` place a formula that will dynamically create your dropdown list from your list items in `Sheet2!A:A` combined with a unique list of user-entered numbers. For example,

   ```
   ={UNIQUE(A:A)); SORT(UNIQUE(
       FILTER(Sheet1!D2:D, ISNUMBER(Sheet1!D2:D))}
   ```
3. Enter the following in your Data validation rule:

   1. Under **Criteria** select `Dropdown (from a range)`
   2. In the range place `Sheet2!B:B`
   3. Under **Advanced options > If the data is invalid** select `Show a warning`

Comment: I edited your question to include more detailed steps for inexperienced users.  Please correct or rollback any changes you don't agree with.  I will remove this comment once you acknowledge it.